# yum list installed *php* on Centos 6 is not showing any php packages but php -v shows php installed version

Tags: php, linux, centos, yum

I want to upgrade my php on centos 6  .

php is already installed on my system but is not shown in yum package list 
these are the commands and results

```
php -v
```

the result is

```
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

and when I type

```
yum list installed *php*
```

the result is

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, refresh-packagekit, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

I also removed php from exclude line of /etc/yum.conf

Comment: Please provide the output from `rpm -qa |grep php`

Comment: the result is nothing

Comment: The command "rpm -qa |grep php" returns no content

Comment: Then it looks like you don't have the RPM's installed - What version do you want and I can show you how to install/upgrade. What specific version of CentOS `uname -a` should give that info.

Comment: The version of CentOS is 6.9 and result of "rpm -?" is some help about this command .

Comment: I use this vps for web hosting and it works . I have installed wordpress on host and I have no problem with it . recently  I have to install laravel 5.5 and so I need to upgrade php .

Comment: how did you install the last (current) version of php?

Comment: my friend has installed it and I don't know how he did .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that in my server PHP is a module that is embeded to Directadmin panel . so I used this link to update my php
[How to upgrade (or install) from PHP v.5.4.x to PHP 7.x (directadmin)](https://forum.directadmin.com/archive/index.php/t-53455.html)